# What is the right torque wrench for a 25 Nm (18.4 lb.ft) oil filter housing?

Tags: torque, oil-filter, torque-wrench

Click-style 1/4″-drive torque wrenches typically go as far up as 20 Nm (14.75 lb.ft). Beam-style 1/4″-drive ones don't even reach that high. Neither is suitable for torquing the oil filter housing at 25 Nm. (It's a 32 mm socket, in case it matters.)

3/8″-drive torque wrenches go from 10-100 Nm. This means that torquing to 25 Nm would be in the hazy/inaccurate part of the range.

1/2″-drive torque wrenches rise to 200 or 250 Nm (or more with longer arms), from maybe 10 or 20 Nm, which means they're simply unsuitable for 25 Nm.

What is the right torque wrench for a 25 Nm (18.4 lb.ft) oil filter housing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it is pretty obvious that if the 1/4" won't go high enough, and the 1/2" won't go low enough, your only choice is the 3/8" drive torque wrench.

According to [this website](https://www.maxprocorp.com/blog/torque-wrench-limitations-accuracy-and-range), states:

> Every torque wrench operates within a given accuracy range, such as ±2-4% over 20% to 100% of full-scale.

Since you didn't state exactly what the accuracy of the torque wrench you're listing, we'll use the 20% low end for this example. You stated the top end of the range is 100 Nm. 20% of that is 20 Nm, which would mean, it is accurate +/-2-4% of the 20 Nm on the lower end. 20 Nm is well below your 25 Nm torque needed, and therefore within the accuracy band you're worried about.

Another thought here is ... the reason they put a torque value on tightening the cap for the oil filter housing is *so you don't over tighten it*. It is ***very*** easy to overtighten and brake the composite oil filter caps. If you tighten then too much and they don't brake, you're looking at the possibility of breaking them when you take it off the next time (this is where I'm supposed to say *don't take this to Jiffy Lube as they overtighten EVERYTHING!* ... sorry shameless rant.)

Bottom line is, the 3/8" torque wrench running from 10-100 Nm should do you just fine for your intended usage.